# how might I add dummy entries to a listView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Does anyone know any simple way to add dummy items to a list view via xml layout? In android studio I can see the dummy items as

```
Item 1
Sub Item 1

Item 2
Sub Item 2

etc
```

but the dummies don't show up on my phone when I run the app. How might I make them show up on the phone as well?

Again, I am precisely looking for a very simple way to make the dummy data visible on the phone as it is in Android Studio. I am working on the layout. I don't want to go create adapters yet.

I already tried

```
tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2"
```

but it didn't make a difference: the phone is still blank.

Comment: You can add dummy entries to any view - but complex views require complex solutions. If you asked for aa screen with "dummy data" what would you expect it to look like? Similarly, the listview can have complex children - and manipulating them is complex. If you have an example child, you may have better luck asking a more focused question like "how can I duplicate this child in a listview?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found 'NO' way to populate "simple_list_item_2" from xml.

If you use simple list item with just one text in each row then it can be achieved easily.

Define a string-array name it `dummy_data`

```
<string-array name="dummy_data" >
        <item>One</item>
        <item>Two</item>
        <item>Three</item>
        <item>Four</item>
        <item>Five</item>
        <item>Six</item>
        <item>Seven</item>
        <item>Eight</item>
        <item>Nine</item>
        <item>Ten</item>
    </string-array>
```

and assign it to `ListView` using `android:entries="@array/dummy_data"`

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/dummy_data" />
```

I will still show below preview in design section but it will populate your array at runtime

```
Item 1
Sub Item 1

Item 2
Sub Item 2

etc
```

for more detail refer [this](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/)

Answer (score 0):

The [tools namespace](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) is only used for seeing data within the development environment (like Android Studio's resource editor) -- it has no effect at all in an actual device (or even in the emulator).

You need to [provide the list data programmatically](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews).

Comment: The framework team should fix this problem then. When I am working on views, I don't want to bother with controllers. MVC is old enough for them to appreciate the importance of separation of concerns. Perhaps someone else here has a more favorable answer. But thanks for your input.

Comment: This is not a "problem", but a feature. The `tools` namespace was created to help designers lay out screens without having to know anything about programming. They just need to use the IDE to view something that usually is close to what the end user will see on an actual device. But, to see the result on an actual device, you (or someone else) needs to do some actual programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write java code you can :

1- replace the listview with a nestedscrollview  (only in test)

2- create a vertical linearlayout inside the nestedscrollview

2- create a view containing a single item of what you want to show in the list .

3- copy and paste the view (single item ) a bunch of times in the linearlayout .

4- you are done !